# Query to combine two columns IF they are different, otherwise just return the result from one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and have two columns that I'd like to combine into one, but only if the data in each column is different.

So, for example, if both columns have the word 'London' in them, then the concatenated column would just show London. But if one column had 'London' and the other column had 'England' then the combined column would show 'London; England'

Is that possible?

I got this code

```
select shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city from pp_finance_bank
```

to concatenate the two columns from a couple of helpful users on this site, but was advised to post the question above as a separate question.

Please let me know if you want me to clarify the question further,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE`:

```
select case when shipto_addr1 = shipto_city then shipto_addr1
            else shipto_addr1 ||', '|| shipto_city
       end address
from pp_finance_bank
```

---

As of query you posted as a comment: everything that isn't aggregated should be part of the `GROUP BY` clause. So:

```
  SELECT homogenized_company,
         contract_no,
         CASE
            WHEN shipto_addr1 = shipto_city THEN shipto_addr1
            ELSE shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city
         END
            address,
         distributor,
         software_vendor,
         SUM (new_annual) acv
    FROM pp_finance_bank
   WHERE contract_no IN ('Z0101-S-00003687')
GROUP BY homogenized_company,
         contract_no,
         CASE
            WHEN shipto_addr1 = shipto_city THEN shipto_addr1
            ELSE shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city
         END,
         distributor,
         software_vendor;
```

Comment: Thanks @littefoot. Do you know how I can add that to this code, please? select HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city, distributor, software_vendor, sum(new_annual) ACV  from pp_finance_bank
where contract_no in ('Z0101-S-00003687')
group by HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city, distributor, software_vendor
;

Comment: Your code worked, but when I replaced the original shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city part in the above query (in the comment) with the CASE statement above, I got a group by  error message. Not sure why?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer and added some more info. Have a look.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.